# Change default arguments of ROC computation (pROC) in the RFE process (caret) - R

Tags: r, r-caret, roc, rfe, proc-r-package

I am computing a SVM-RFE model using `"ROC"` as the metric, with the `rfe` function (`caret` package). To my knowledge, the `rfe` algorithm optimizes the AUC values using the `roc` function of the `pROC` package, with its predefined arguments. However, I would like to set the `direction` argument to `"<"` instead of `"auto"` because in some cases the resulting average AUC is computed in reverse (my data is not very good...). This problem is explained in the answer here: [Difference in average AUC computation using ROCR and pROC (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252317/difference-in-average-auc-computation-using-rocr-and-proc-r)

How could I change this default argument value of the `roc` function in the `rfe` computation?

I have tried this simple option, but it does not work:

```
svmRFE_NG3 <- rfe(x = TAll[,2:50],
               y = TAll[,1],
               sizes = seq(1,42),
               metric = "ROC",
               levels = c("BREAST","LUNG"),
               direction = "<",
               rfeControl = FSctrl,
               ## Options to train()
               method = "svmLinear",
               tuneLength = 10,
               preProc = c("center", "scale"),
               ## Inner resampling process
               trControl = TRctrl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the source code of caret, and it doesn't seem to be readily possible at the moment. Arguments are not passed down to the call to the `roc` function.

I would suggest submitting a request for enhancement on [the github repository of the package](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues). Max Kuhn the maintainer is pretty responsive and you have a good chance to see this implemented in a future version.

Comment: I know that I should avoid this type of comments here, but I have to thank you @Calimo for all your help because I am new with R and it is being difficult to deal with all these kind of problems I have!