# Sensitivity and specificity reported by coords() and confusionMatrix() in R at optimal cut-point don't match

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, proc, roc

I trained an SVM with linear kernel in R to classify patients with a disease, used the predict() function to generate predicted probabilities on a testing set using the SVM model, then generated an ROC curve using the roc() function from the pROC library. I also used coords() to calculate the optimal cut-point using Youden's index. coords() returned a cut-point of 0.8489392, specificity of 0.6250000, and sensitivity of 0.7954545.

When I attempt to generate a confusion matrix using predictions made at this cut-point, I get a sensitivity of 0.20455 and specificity of 0.37500 and cannot figure out why they don't match the sensitivity and specificity reported by coords().

This is the only model of several models where the sensitivity and specificity reported by both functions do not match.

Code below:

```
svm_linear <- train(ercp_chole ~ stone_any_modality + age + peak_pre_bili + max_cbd_dia_any,
    data = chole_training,
    method = "svmLinear",
    trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3, classProbs=TRUE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary),
    na.action = na.exclude,
    preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
    metric = "ROC",
    tuneLength = 10
)

pprob_svm_linear <- predict(svm_linear, chole_testing, type="prob")
svm_linear_roc <- roc(chole_testing$ercp_chole, pprob_svm_linear[,2], auc=TRUE)
coords(svm_linear_roc, "best", "threshold", transpose=TRUE, best.method="youden")

confusionMatrix(factor( ifelse(pprob_svm_linear[, "chole_pos"] > 0.8489392, "chole_pos", "chole_neg") ), chole_testing$ercp_chole, positive="chole_pos")
```

Results of the call to roc():

```
Setting levels: control = chole_neg, case = chole_pos
Setting direction: controls > cases
```

Results of the call to coords():

```
threshold specificity sensitivity
0.8489392   0.6250000   0.7954545
```

Results of the call to confusionMatrix():

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

           Reference
Prediction  chole_neg chole_pos
  chole_neg         3        35
  chole_pos         5         9

               Accuracy : 0.2308
                 95% CI : (0.1253, 0.3684)
    No Information Rate : 0.8462
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1

                  Kappa : -0.1659

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 4.533e-06

            Sensitivity : 0.20455
            Specificity : 0.37500
         Pos Pred Value : 0.64286
         Neg Pred Value : 0.07895
             Prevalence : 0.84615
         Detection Rate : 0.17308
   Detection Prevalence : 0.26923
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.28977

       'Positive' Class : chole_pos
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the full output of the script. I believe it contains some important informations.

Comment: Also most likely the answer will be the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37252317/333599

Comment: Hi, I updated the original post with the output from the call to roc(). As you guessed, roc() automatically set direction as controls < cases whereas the roc() call for the other models were automatically set to controls > cases. What is the significance of this and how can I decide on a direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37252317/333599), pROC can automatically detect whether control (negative) observations have higher or lower values than cases (positives). As you mentioned you can see this in the output of the `roc` function:

```
Setting levels: control = chole_neg, case = chole_pos
Setting direction: controls > cases
```

On the contrary, `confusionMatrix` cannot do that and will always assume that positive observations have higher values. As a result, the ROC curve is "reversed" and [has an AUC < 0.5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/266387/36682).

It is a good idea to set the levels (in negative, positive order) and direction explicitly. For that you need to look at your data and understand whether the controls or cases have higher values, and whether that makes sense. Then you can call the `roc` function with those values explicitly. For instance if in your case negatives have indeed higher values:

```
svm_linear_roc <- roc(chole_testing$ercp_chole,
                      pprob_svm_linear[,2],
                      auc=TRUE,
                      levels = c("chole_neg", "chole_pos"),
                      direction = ">")
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What do you mean by higher values? I'm assuming if I choose a direction and the resulting sensitivity and specificity returned by roc() matches that of confusionMatrix() and I've verified that "correct" predictions are in fact correct and "incorrect" predictions are incorrect, I have chose the correct direction?

Comment: @loperamide you're predicting values with SVM (scores, probabilities or whatever you chose). You need to get a sense of what those values are, what is low, what is high, what it means, and which class is higher or lower.

Comment: @loperamide in other words you should look at the data!